# Ram rows and columns

Tags: memory

Does an addressable column of ram represent a byte of data or a bit of data? I haven't found a reliable source that answers this question. If it does represent a byte does it always?

Comment: CPUs only have byte (and/or word) memory addresses. So the address passed from the CPU to the memory subsystem is for at least a byte-sized transfer of memory data. The RAM **chips** on the **module** could be 1-bit wide or maybe 4-or-more-bits wide.  So an internal (to the memory module) address could be selecting only 1 (or 4 or more) bit(s) from each chip of a group of chips on the module.  But this sub-address is ***internal*** to the module, and is of no concern to the CPU or the programmer (unless there were memory errors and/or you were writing a memory diagnostic program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, an address in ram always points to a byte. If it pointed to a bit, the address table would be eight times as big as the data table! That would be very inefficient.

Comment: I guess what I mean does the columns address select or bit line, not the virtual memory address, select a bit or byte or more to be read from the hardware ram module? I apologize if this was redundant, I just wanted to make sure I'm asking the right question

Comment: *"an address in ram always points to a byte"* -- That's a typical (and modern) convention. But it is a convention, and not a hard and fast rule. I have programmed computers that addressed **16-bit memory words**; there was no single-byte access to memory at all on a Data General Nova computer.  *"the address table"* -- Maybe CAM or cache memory require an "address table", but not RAM.